# How to get a link from fb wall and post to my website?

Tags: php, facebook

In php and i am a starter. So correct me if i am wrong. What I am asking is, hw to grab a link[generated by farmville] on FB wall and post to my web site when a user register to my site with is FB [SSO] id.

Answer (score -1):

i thing for this you have to use facebook account auth. and after approve the authentication, use the fql query, to get the link of that account holder.

follow the link for [facebook account authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Thank you. You got my point finally. I know that FB auth is required. But I am pointing towards FQL query.

Comment: @JayaSankarYakkala for FQL, i just know that if you want to access the details of any user from facebook, you need the permission that is a part of auth, and for FQL query read the facebook graph api, i think through graph api, i don't know more about facebook graph api.